# How render specific data from axios call in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios, state, render

need some help.

I am making a 'get' request using axios in React to an NFL API and then I am rendering the response to the webpage. I only want to render players whose positions are QB, RB and WR. I do not need all of the other players. Here is a sample of what one player object looks like in my 'get' request:

```
    {
        "PlayerID": 20841,
        "Team": "NYG",
        "Number": 8,
        **"Position": "QB",**
        "Height": "6'5",
        "Weight": 221,
        "Name": "Daniel Jones"
    }
```

I am able to make the API call (I removed the URL from playersURL) and update the 'data' state with the response. From there I am able to setState and render all the players. But I do not know how to only render players that match the position parameters. Any idears? Thanks!!

```
    import React from "react";
    import "./General.css";
    const axios = require("axios");

    export default class General extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          loading: true,
          data: []
        };
      }

      getData() {
        const playersURL =
          "";
        axios.get(playersURL).then((res) => {
          var data = res.data;

          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var playerPosition = data[i].Position;

            if (
              playerPosition === "QB" ||
              playerPosition === "RB" ||
              playerPosition === "WR"
            ) {
                console.log(playerPosition)
            }
          }

          this.setState({ data: data, loading: false });
        });
      }

      async componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
      }

      render() {
        
        if (this.state.loading) {
          return <div className='loadingDiv'>Calling the API, one moment please!</div>;
        }

        return (
          <div className="container">
              {this.state.data.map((d) => (
                <div className="playerDiv" key={d.PlayerID}>
                  {d.PlayerID} - {d.Name} - {d.Position} - {d.Team}
                </div>
              ))}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to filter players in specific position, right?

Comment: Exactly. I want to only render players whose position are 'QB', 'RB', and 'WR'. I'm able to loop through the data and console log it, but it only logs just the positions, not the rest of the information like the players ID, name, or team.

Comment: I understand, you can see if my answer is what you want

Answer (score 1):

try this one, filter response data in promise.then

```
getData() {
  const playersURL = "";
  axios.get(playersURL).then((res) => {
    const data = res.data;
    this.setState({
      data: data?.filter(player => ['QB', 'RB', 'WR'].includes(player.Position)),
      loading: false
    });
  });
}
```

If the amount of response data is not too large, you can also put the filter in render

```
render() {
  if (this.state.loading) {
    return <div className='loadingDiv'>Calling the API, one moment please!</div>;
  }

  const filterData = this.state.data?.filter(d =>
    ['QB', 'RB', 'WR'].includes(d.Position)
  )

  return (
    <div className="container">
        {filterData.map((d) => (
          <div className="playerDiv" key={d.PlayerID}>
            {d.PlayerID} - {d.Name} - {d.Position} - {d.Team}
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: no problem, btw if my answer can solve your problem, can you vote me? thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    axios.get(playersURL).then((res) => {
      var data = res.data;
      const filteredData = data?.filter(player => player.Position === "QB" || 
                                       player.Position === "RB" || 
                                       player.Position === "WR" );

      this.setState({ data: filteredData , loading: false });
    });
```